# Identifying objects in Rails - Sometimes with :id and sometimes with the object itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

another pretty general question about Ruby on rails:

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

Looking at the find method, I call it with the parameter id (which is incoming through the REST request, I guess)

Now here

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
                method: :delete,
                data:{confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

I assemble the route with the id of both comment.post + comment. To me it seems like the comment.post.id and comment.id are given implicitly (magic^^), which is fine for me, but I tried to code it, and I get an exception.

Why is it that way? And can somebody guide me to the right part of the documentation where exactly this behavior is described? Im pretty lost with all this smart and automatic stuff ruby does....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing two very different things.

This is doing a request to ActiveRecord to find an instance of `Post` with a matching `id`:

```
Post.find(id)
```

This next line is using the built in `UrlHelper` to construct an HTML link in your view for the given `resource`:

```
link_to 'Link Text', resource
```

In your particular case, you specify the `:method` as being `:delete`. Through the configuration in your `routes.rb` file, rails then maps this `DELETE` request for a `[POST, Comment]` nested resource to the `posts_comment_path` and passes in the `post_id` for `comment.post` and the `id` for `comment`.

This isn't so magic if you dig through the Rails source code a little. The `link_to` documentation states that the second argument can accept any valid options accepted by `url_for`. ([click here for link_to docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to))

The `url_for` documentation ([available here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for)) says this:

```
<%= url_for(@workshop) %>
# calls @workshop.to_param which by default returns the id
# => /workshops/5

# to_param can be re-defined in a model to provide different URL names:
# => /workshops/1-workshop-name
```

So, not so magic really. It's definitely worth spending a little time following the chain of calls that rails makes when you call something like `link_to` as it demystifies a lot of what you initially see as quite complex.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for this extensive explanation. Ill check the docs and everything right now :D